# How to display the body of an email in the columns of an email-enabled library or list?

Tags: 2010, email-enabled-library

Salvete!  I have an email-enabled library that can receive emails.  I can see that there is a possible column for `subject`, `from address` and `sender`, etc., but I don't see one for `body`.  How can I get one?  I don't mind using a list instead of a library.  I just want to see the contents of the emails appear in the list view.

Comment: Multiple line textbox with Full Html enabled ?

Comment: Well, how do I get the body of the email into that?

Comment: @BGM I deleted my answer. Sorry, I didn't notice you were talking about libraries.

Comment: My fault, actually - I suppose the title and the question detail conflict.  Sometimes SP is confusing.  I was using a "library" because I couldn't figure out how to get email to show in a simple list in the first place.  I'll fix my question title.

Answer (score 2):

You would likely need to use a list item event receiver and when an item is created get a handle on the attached email and fill in a custom text field with the text. There are all sorts of potential issues with formatting, though.

Since these are relatively common tasks I'm just going to give links for the reference. If you need additional help, just let me know.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx

http://blog.mediawhole.com/2009/08/retrieving-list-items-attachments.html

Comment: I suppose I would have to do some code-editing and deploy custom solutions, no?  I still don't have a dev environment, and am a bit lacking in this area.

Comment: I think that's the only option... I'm glad you are thinking about a test environment. Don't be this guy. http://www.troll.me/images/the-most-interesting-man-in-the-world/i-dont-always-load-test-my-code-but-when-i-do-i-do-it-in-production.jpg